# Using LinearLayout instead of RecyclerView in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

Since I'm using a fixed menu for the navigation drawer I tried to use LinearLayout in DrawerLayout's second child instead of RecyclerView/ListView to make it easier to code. But the result is a full-screen linearlayout.  Is there any way to use a regular view (like linearlayout) in DrawerLayout?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bye world"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "Is there any way to use a regular view (like linearlayout) in DrawerLayout?" - Yes. You have to setup your `DrawerLayout` and its child `View`s correctly.

Comment: How to setup DrawerLayout for using LinearLayout instead of RecyclerView?

Comment: The same way you would for the `RecyclerView`, substituting a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: What does the XML for your drawer layout look like? Isn't there a view inside it?

Comment: The only thing that you should keep in mind is: first child is your main content and second child is your drawer content (which could be any view group, as far as I know).

Comment: code added to the question

Comment: You need to set a `layout_gravity` of `left`/`right` or `start`/`end` on the `LinearLayout` for the `DrawerLayout` to recognize it as a drawer.

Comment: I've done that, now the result on IDE is not full-screen, but in real device it's still full-screen

Comment: Set an exact measure for the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_width`; e.g., `240dp`.

Comment: It was an IDE issue, fixed by re-writing the code. now it's fixed and OK; please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `View` can act as a drawer in a `DrawerLayout`. For the `DrawerLayout` to recognize a `View` as a drawer, it must have a `layout_gravity` attribute set to `left`/`right` or `start`/`end`, depending on which vertical edge you want the drawer attached to.

The drawer's `layout_height` is normally `match_parent`, so that the drawer spans the full height of the `DrawerLayout`, and its `layout_width` is normally an exact measure - e.g., `240dp` - to keep a consistent width, independent of its contents.

Additionally, the drawer `View` must be listed last within the `DrawerLayout` to maintain the correct z-order, otherwise it will be covered by the content `View` and won't receive click events.